# Having created a new account, I automatically enter it

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Having created a new account, I automatically enter it.
How do I prevent my account from being created?

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Пользователь добавлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             progressDialog.dismiss();
         } else {
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Пользователь не добавлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             progressDialog.dismiss();
         }
     }
});
```

May be need workes whis admin sdk?
May be who worked with admin sdk firebase android?
Are there any examples or lessons on working with admin sdk?
For I do not understand how to work with this.

Comment: Didn't I just answer that in your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42765724/how-to-not-log-in-to-the-created-account#comment72648333_42765724? If my comments were not clear, please respond in that question instead of opening a new one.

Answer (score 1):

The way I understand Firebase to work is that if the task is successful then Firebase actually actually signs in the user.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); 
            //Ther will be a current user at this point. This is the way Firebase just works.

                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Пользователь не добавлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
```

So you can actually get the user after the task is successful because the user is automatically set if the task is successful. If you would not like there to be any user when the task is successful. You can call

```
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```

This will sign out the user and when you call

```
Firebase.getInstance().getCurrentUser()
```

This will return nothing, that way there will be no user in your system.

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(em, pass).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); 
        //Ther will be a current user at this point. This is the way Firebase just works.
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();// sign out the user
                Firebase.geInstance().getCurrentUser(); // this will now be null
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Пользователь не добавлен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Firebase.geInstance.getCurrentUser(); 
Firebase is highlighted in red

Comment: Firebase.geInstance().getCurrentUser(); It has been corrected. Frank has already answered your question. You should not duplicate your questions.